# JOptionPane.showOptionDialog using custom panel is not working properly

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

In my application, there is a need to display JOptionPane.showOptionDialog frequently when user provide input.

Sometimes it will not displayed and it waits for user input and hangs.

Here i attached the sample code to reproduce the same.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.ToolTipManager;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument;
import javax.swing.text.Style;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class TestJOptionPane {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int index = 0; index < 20; index++) {
        String serverMessage = "Test question message index = "+index;
        String hintText = "Test question hint index = "+index;

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(0,4));
        JPanel answerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        StyleContext context = new StyleContext();
        StyledDocument document = new DefaultStyledDocument(context);

        Style style = context.getStyle(StyleContext.DEFAULT_STYLE);
        StyleConstants.setFontFamily(style, "Dialog");
        StyleConstants.setFontSize(style, 12);
        StyleConstants.setBold(style, true);

        try {
          document.insertString(document.getLength(), serverMessage, style);
        } catch (BadLocationException badLocationException) {
          System.out.println(badLocationException.getMessage());
        }

        JTextPane questionTA = new JTextPane(document);
        questionTA.setEditable(false);
        questionTA.setOpaque(false);

        final JTextField answerField = new JTextField();
        answerField.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(410,23) );
        answerField.requestFocus();

        JLabel hint = new JLabel();

        ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setDismissDelay(10000);
        hint.setText("Hint");
    //  hint.setIcon(Utility.getIcon("HintQuestion.png"));

        answerPanel.add(answerField);
        answerPanel.add(new JPanel().add(hint));                        
        answerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 30));
        mainPanel.add(questionTA,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainPanel.add(answerPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        hint.setToolTipText(hintText);

        String[] options = {"OK"};
        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, mainPanel, "Test showOptionDialog", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
    }
}
}
```

The o/p displayed like

"Test question message index = 0" and click OK

"Test question message index = 1" and click OK

On a random, the JOptionPane.showOptionDialog not displayed.

Please anyone can help me!!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change you code as below.

```
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, mainPanel, "Test showOptionDialog", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
                }
            });
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Beniton. Actually my method looks like 


    public Object SendResponse(String status, String serverMessage, String functionName,String hintText) throws RemoteException {
        // Above code and return user input to server 
     }


If i use invokeAndWait, it is seperate thread then how do i return answerField.getText() to my caller method

Comment: @Lokesh You can implement ObserverPattern. Make the textfield observable and have a observer which should get notified when to return the userInput.